# document.querySelectorAll doesn't apply despite the HTML adjusting

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I'm trying to get all the divs within a div with document.querySelectorAll. Interestingly, when I set in the JS the height to 1000, the explorer's scroller enlarges accordingly (only the balloon doesn't get bigger). What am I doing wrong?

```js
'use strict';

var gElBalloons;

function init() {
  gElBalloons = document.querySelectorAll('.balloons');

  setInterval(moveBalloons, 1000);
}

function moveBalloons() {
  for (var i = 0; i < gElBalloons.length; i++) {
    gElBalloons[i].style.height = 1000 + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10%;
}

.balloon-1 {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 145px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 80%;
  position: absolute;
}

.balloon-2 {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 145px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 80%;
  left: 40%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Balloons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div class="balloons">
    <div class="balloon-1"></div>

    <div class="balloon-2"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

For now, I just want to test and make sure it works correctly.

Comment: Can you add the CSS? You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: you only have one element with `class="balloons"`, and that is the container for the "balloon-1" and "balloon-2" divs. If, as I think. you intended to set their height, you have to give them the class and remove it from the container

Comment: although it's hard to see what you want to do, because you can only set the height to 1000px once so the `setInterval` is pointless

Comment: @RobinZigmond I suspect this is a simplification, and in the real application it does more to "move" the balloons.

Comment: @Barmar Hi Barmar, updated with CSS

Comment: What's the problem? I ran your code and inspected the `balloons` DIV. It has `style="height: 1000px;"` as expected.

Comment: @Barmar The balloons do not adjust to 1000px height when executed. As you suspected, this is merely a test to see I am properly using querySelectorAll before I proceed to move the balloons properly.

Comment: As @RobinZigmond pointed out, you're not setting the heights of the balloons. You're setting the height of the div that contains them.

Comment: Thank you kindly, Barmar and @RobinZIgmond

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your selector selected the wrong `div`. If you want to make the ball bigger, you should select `balloon-1` and `balloon-2` instead of their container `balloons`.

```js
'use strict';

var gElBalloons;

function init() {
  gElBalloons = document.querySelectorAll('.balloons > div');

  setInterval(moveBalloons, 1000);
}

function moveBalloons() {
  for (var i = 0; i < gElBalloons.length; i++) {
    gElBalloons[i].style.height = 1000 + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10%;
}

.balloon-1 {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 145px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 80%;
  position: absolute;
}

.balloon-2 {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 145px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 80%;
  left: 40%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Balloons</title>

</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div class="balloons">
    <div class="balloon-1"></div>

    <div class="balloon-2"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```